# Chrome is showing a div at the wrong location

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

[image]I'm moving some divs around and it works fine in Firefox and IE. But in chrome it freezes the display of the div sometimes (even though the div is actually still moving).

Also the div is cursor:pointer and when I hover over where it should be (not where it is drawn) only then the cursor turns to pointer.

Also if I switch tabs in chrome and switch back, it draws the div at the correct spot.

Also if I change anything about the div (like background color) in the "Inspect Element" window, the div snaps into place.

How do I fix this?

The light blue box is where the div really is internally. Notice all the boxes in the left column are not drawn at the correct spot.

Comment: Can you show your js code?

Comment: It works fine by itself, I only noticed the problem when I added my code as a section of a page to this complex website I'm working on, which seems to be causing my javascript to run slower and then chrome freaks out. Maybe if I introduce lag I can repeat the error.

Comment: So I'm guessing that this isn't a common Chrome but with a generally known solution?

Comment: My code is 2000 lines of javascript that I'm not allowed to make public yet. Not that it matters what my code is since this is obviously a browser bug with a generic cause that someone should know by now.

Comment: @curtis So, why reporting here? This is not a bugs repository.

Comment: I'm asking how people normally solve this. Notice the question mark in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that this only happens when one of the divs happens to move into a google ad. Then since this is Google chrome and a Google ad, it freaks out and shuts of rendering my content, so that I don't mess with their ads.

I guess the solution is to not allow your divs to run into ads, even though your divs are in a container that's away from the ads and has overflow:hidden. So the div that is hitting the ad isn't even being displayed but still chrome doesn't like it.